# sklearn GLM classificiation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, glm

Is there a way to implement a generalized linear model to classification problems in sklearn? Since there isn't a classification class for that I thought of applying a sigmoid function to regression results. Is there an easy way to do it with sklearn?

I've tried stacking but `StackingClassifier` does not support regressors as estimators.

```
glm = TweedieRegressor()
logit = LogisticRegression(penalty = 'none')

GLM_logistic = StackingClassifier(estimators = [('glm', glm)], final_estimator = logit)

GLM_logistic.fit(X, y)
```

This gives

```
ValueError: The estimator TweedieRegressor should be a classifier.
```

Comment: maybe create bins for the target data and use Classifier to predict those bins.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to force it:

```
glm = TweedieRegressor()
glm._estimator_type = 'classifier'
logit = LogisticRegression()

GLM_logistic = StackingClassifier(estimators = [('glm', glm)], final_estimator = logit)
```

If someone has an idea of how to improve this solution, please leave an answer.